# Golang bytes.Buffer - Passby value issue

Tags: go, pass-by-value

The below golang(go1.10.2) code will give an unexpected output

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    //Commenting the below line will fix the problem
    b.WriteString("aas-")
    fmt.Printf("Before Calling - \"%s\"\n", b.String())
    b = makeMeMad(b)
    fmt.Printf("FinalValue - \"%s\"\n", b.String())
}

func makeMeMad(b bytes.Buffer) bytes.Buffer {
    b.WriteString("xcxxcx asdasdas dasdsd asdasdasdasd")
    fmt.Printf("Write More - \"%s\"\n", b.String())

    /*
        //This will fix the problem
        var newBuffer bytes.Buffer
        newBuffer.WriteString(b.String())
        return newBuffer
    */
    return b
}
```

Output

```
Before Calling - "aas-"
Write More - "aas-xcxxcx asdasdas dasdsd asdasdasdasd"
FinalValue - "aas-                                   "
```

I was expecting "aas-xcxxcx asdasdas dasdsd asdasdasdasd" in the last line of output. Could anyone please explain.

Comment: The problem has been posted to be an issue on github of Go, you can watch it here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26462

Comment: So the answer for what you experience is here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26462#issuecomment-406256821. `bytes.Buffer` should never be passed as-is in the first place, always pass a pointer to it.

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood `bytes.Buffer` contain among other unexported fields `bootstrap` array and `buf` slice. While buffer content is small slice points to internal array to avoid allocation. When you pass  `bytes.Buffer` argument as value, function receives a copy. Slice is reference type, so this copy's slice continue to point on the original buffer's array. When you write to this copy's slice you actually write to original's bootstrap array, copy's array stay unchanged("aas-" in our case). Then you return this copy and you can print it. But when you assign it to variable containing original, bootstrap array first assigned("aas-") and then `buf` slice pointed on it.
Bootstrap array is [64]byte, so you can use long string literals >64 in you code snippet and [see](https://play.golang.org/p/BbkBGBTIije) things works as expected when buffer allocate buf slice.
Also [`here`](https://play.golang.org/p/r5eeugqqDSM) simplified example trying to show why all this looks so contrintuitive.

Answer (score -1):

It is mentioned in [Golang FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#different_method_sets) section as:

> If an interface value contains a pointer *T, a method call can obtain
>   a value by dereferencing the pointer, but if an interface value
>   contains a value T, there is no useful way for a method call to obtain
>   a pointer.
>
> Even in cases where the compiler could take the address of a value to
>   pass to the method, if the method modifies the value the changes will
>   be lost in the caller. As an example, if the Write method of
>   bytes.Buffer used a value receiver rather than a pointer, this code:

```
var buf bytes.Buffer
io.Copy(buf, os.Stdin)
```

> would copy standard input into a copy of buf, not into buf itself

The error is because you're not passing the address of buffer inside `makeMeMad` function. That's why it has not override the original buffer inside main function.
Pass address to the created buffer to append string to the existing buffer value.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    //Commenting the below line will fix the problem
    b.WriteString("aas-")
    fmt.Printf("Before Calling - \"%s\"\n", b.String())
    makeMeMad(&b)
    fmt.Printf("FinalValue - \"%s\"\n", b.String())
}

func makeMeMad(b *bytes.Buffer) {
    b.WriteString("xcxxcx asdasdas dasdsd asdasdasdasd")
    fmt.Printf("Write More - \"%s\"\n", b.String())

    /*
        //This will fix the problem
        var newBuffer bytes.Buffer
        newBuffer.WriteString(b.String())
        return newBuffer
    */
}
```

[Playground Example](https://play.golang.org/p/PrDSEzoSghV)

Or you can assign the returned buffer value to a new variable and you will get the updated buffer value.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    //Commenting the below line will fix the problem
    b.WriteString("aas-")
    fmt.Printf("Before Calling - \"%s\"\n", b.String())
    ab := makeMeMad(b)
    fmt.Printf("FinalValue - \"%s\"\n", ab.String())
}

func makeMeMad(b bytes.Buffer) bytes.Buffer {
    b.WriteString("xcxxcx asdasdas dasdsd asdasdasdasd")
    fmt.Printf("Write More - \"%s\"\n", b.String())

    /*
        //This will fix the problem
        var newBuffer bytes.Buffer
        newBuffer.WriteString(b.String())
        return newBuffer
    */
    return b
}
```

Working Code on [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/2aWg2cknbm8)

Or you can create a global buffer to change the value inside the buffer whenever it is written by any function.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

var b bytes.Buffer

func main() {
    //Commenting the below line will fix the problem
    b.WriteString("aas-")
    fmt.Printf("Before Calling - \"%s\"\n", b.String())
    b := makeMeMad(b)
    fmt.Printf("FinalValue - \"%s\"\n", b.String())
}

func makeMeMad(b bytes.Buffer) bytes.Buffer {
    b.WriteString("xcxxcx asdasdas dasdsd asdasdasdasd")
    fmt.Printf("Write More - \"%s\"\n", b.String())

    /*
        //This will fix the problem
        var newBuffer bytes.Buffer
        newBuffer.WriteString(b.String())
        return newBuffer
    */
    return b
}
```

[Playground Example](https://play.golang.org/p/_C0fCg5sV59)

Comment: But he does write `b = ...` right? So the value is re-written into `b`, isn't it?

Comment: @leafbebop check the edited answer OP is passing the copy of buffer to the function.

Comment: And he returns a copy of modified buffer which is re-assigned to the orignal variable.

Comment: @leafbebop yes the value updated the state of the buffer but on return it discarded the changes

Comment: @leafbebop There is nothing new if you check it carefully you are still not writing to the main buffer. If you really wants to append something to the buffer use this https://play.golang.org/p/ukqEyZaaCLI.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176320/discussion-between-himanshu-and-leaf-bebop).